# How to get my all facebook posts by group ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

As the fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher, So I am not able to access the data using fql. Is there any way to fetch only my posts by group id.

Please correct me, if Im wrong.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want all of your posts (facebook status updates) or do you want all posts of yourself within a specific facebook group?

Comment: Yes, I  want all posts of myself within a specific facebook group.
Thanks for reply...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get all posts of a group via the GraphAPI endpoint

```
v2.5/{group-id}/feed
```

Anyways, you are not able to perform this action if you are not "Admin" of the specific group. You need the additional permission of 'user_managed_groups'.

To drill it down to a specific user query against

```
v2.5/{group-id}/feed?fields=from,message
```

Then you have have the users' id and the message. Just iterate of the response and filter out by the user of your choice.

Comment: Hey @Markus, thanks for reply. I am getting the feed as you have mentioned. But now I need feed to be filtered by specific member of the group and not all feeds. If you have any idea on this then it would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: @user3293222 Added the solution you requested. If it helped you I would appreciate if you mark my answer with the green tick mark, as the result to your question.

Comment: Thanks,
Can I get the feeds of particular group by author Id...?

Comment: @user3293222 No the v2.5/{group-id}/feed endpoint can not be filtered by  a given field (in your case username)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, So finally I have to filter the result by user id.

Comment: The problem is using this end point we get only limited records per request. So if users id is in 60th request ..it will take lots of time to fetch...